# mongoDB unique, compound index with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, indexing, pymongo

trying to create a compound unique index in mongoDb with PyMongo to avoid duplicates.
Here is my code;

```
index = collection.create_index([('date', 1), ('name', 1)], {'unique' : True})
```

It is raising the following error.

```
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_pinned_address'
```

If I change the dict in the argument to a tuple, I get the same error except 'tuple' object.
I just went ahead and created the index through mongo compass, but would like to know a solution with PyMongo.
Any ideas?

Comment: `unique` is a kwarg, not an arg. Try: `index = collection.create_index([('date', 1), ('name', 1)], unique=True)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the official pymongo documentation:
https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index

`unique` should be a kwarg, therefore, your code should be:

```
index = collection.create_index([('date', 1), ('name', 1)], unique=True)
```